# Rails doesn't recreate mysql views in the test database, even when config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

We have some mysql Views in our development and test databases that were created via an execute(sql) statement in a migration. Rails' default schema.rb creates these views as tables. When config.active_record.schema_format is set to :sql, these views are not created at all.

Is there a setting to ensure these views are re-created in the test db?

If not, can anyone suggest a workaround?

NB, the `show create table` for this view is something like:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `sales_reports` AS select ...
```

and the view is included in `show tables`

After investigation, it looks like activerecord does this intentionally.

active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb

Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: I know it doesnt answer your question but i found [sql views](https://github.com/aeden/rails_sql_views) gem to be a good alternative...

Answer (score 8):

Be sure to [read this section of the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps).

Ensure in the application block in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Then you can use this Rake task to dump the schema, though it should be dumped/updated whenever you do a migrate/etc. because of that setting above:

```
rake db:structure:dump
```

Your dumped structure should be in `db/structure.sql`. It should look like a dump schema file from your DB, i.e. not including data, with the exception of migration data that will be put at the end (at least for postgres).

When using `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` your `db/schema.rb` is *not* updated by default whenever you do a migration, because `db/schema.rb` is not meant to be a full schema SQL dump. However, some tools like IntelliJ Rubymine and IDea with the Ruby plugin like that file to be there, so in your Rakefile add these (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646840/how-to-make-rake-dbmigrate-generate-schema-rb-when-using-sql-schema-format)):

```
Rake::Task["db:migrate"].enhance do
  if ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format == :sql
    Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke
  end
end

Rake::Task["db:rollback"].enhance do
  if ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format == :sql
    Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke
  end
end
```

When the test DB is recreated by Rails, it will use `db/structure.sql` as a base if using `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`. If you rollback or make changes to the DB externally and redump using the command above or doing migrate, etc., it will also update `db/structure.sql` (and `db/schema.rb` with those tasks above, though `db/schema.rb` doesn't fully encompass the info from the schema dump).

Comment: Making the above changes still doesn't seem to cause the MySQL views to be written to the `structure.sql`; so they remain unavailable to the testing database (observed with Rails 3.2.22, ruby 2.3.4p301)

Comment: This solution worked for me: http://weavingcode.blogspot.com/2011/12/mysql-views-and-rails-easy-way.html