# How to make rake db:migrate generate schema.rb when using :sql schema format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, dbmigrate, schema.rb

If using the this option in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

then when you do:

```
rake db:migrate
```

it only dumps the `db/structure.sql`. I know it isn't using the `db/schema.rb` since it is using the `:sql` option, but how can you make `rake db:migrate` generate `db/schema.rb` also?

We need that because RubyMine 4.5 and IntelliJ IDea 11 use `db/schema.rb` for autocompletion of columns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To generate/update `db/schema.rb` even if using the `:sql` option, you can put this in your `Rakefile`:

```
Rake::Task["db:migrate"].enhance do
  if ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format == :sql
    Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke
  end
end
```

That should be fine for IDea and RubyMine.

For others that just want the file for reference, you might want to rename it to something else like `db/schema.rb.backup` so it won't be confusing. To do that:

```
Rake::Task["db:migrate"].enhance do
  if ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format == :sql
    Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke
    File.rename(File.expand_path('../db/schema.rb', __FILE__), File.expand_path('../db/schema.rb.backup', __FILE__))
  end
end
```

(Note: Using `../` in paths in `Rakefile` because `__FILE__` evaluates to a path that ends in `/Rakefile`.)

Comment: thx work perfect. Only change I need to do is the renamed file, because I use sometimes `scaffold` (this search schema with the regexp //schema[^/]*.rb$ ). I change `File.rename(File.expand_path('../db/schema.rb', __FILE__), File.expand_path('../db/schema.backup.rb', __FILE__))`

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work for me, I had to sandwich the call like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format = :ruby
Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke
ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format = :sql
```

Thanks Gary for your suggestions.

Comment: Is this with Rails7? AFAIK there were some changes in this area in Rails7.

Comment: I'm not sure if the changes in Rails 7 would help reshape the solution...Based on what I'm reading here: https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/08/30/rails-db-schema-supports-schema-format-env/